# Быстрое воспроизведение генерации речи Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx3, tts

Есть генератор речи, как можно наиболее быстро воспроизвести запись генерации голоса, либо, если это возможно - поток звука через библиотеки вроде pygame или kivy(неважно)

Я использовал способ воспроизведения системой wav файла, но хотел бы поменять на более быстрый способ

```
def loraSpeak(text):
    print('LORA:' +text)
    global LNG2
    obj = gTTS(text=text, lang=LNG2, slow=False)
    obj.save('asisResp.wav')
    os.system('start asisResp.wav')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная строчка медленная по многим причинам:

```
os.system('start asisResp.wav')
```

Как минимум, это:

1. Команда, указанная в кавычках - передаётся в shell операционной системы.
2. Далее shell ОС её обрабатывает: синтаксически проверяет команду, проверяет есть ли такая команда, проверяет, разрешена ли она пользователю, ищет соответствие типу файла и программы, запускает соответствующую программу с определённым параметром, выполняет её, читает указанный файл с физического диска и перенаправляет поток вывода в STDOUT и поток ошибок в STDERR соответственно.

и многие другие шаги, которые я упустил, но которые выполняются каждый раз.

Лучшим решением будет использование библиотечного проигрывателя, типа pygame и других. Таким образом удастся избежать многих лишних шагов.

Так же желательно при получении ответа от gTTS сразу же воспроизводить, минуя сохранения файла диск - преобразовать ответ gTTS в более удобоваримое для библиотеки pygame, чем mp3 или wav файл - например, массив байт.

Посмотрев исходники библиотеки gTTS можно увидеть метод `write_to_fp`
https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/blob/master/gtts/tts.py
Который возвращает файло-подобный объект, то есть контент самого файла, который сохраняется методом save.

Данный объект можно использовать в совокупности с возможностью библиотеки pygame

```
pip install pygame
```

Тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```
from io import BytesIO
import pygame
from gtts import gTTS

LNG2 = 'ru'

pygame.init()

def loraSpeak(text):
    print('LORA:' + text)
    global LNG2
    obj = gTTS(text=text, lang=LNG2, slow=False)
    fp = BytesIO()
    obj.write_to_fp(fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(fp)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)

loraSpeak('привет, я - Лора')
```

или библиотеки IPython:

```
pip install IPython
```

...

```
from gtts import gTTS
from IPython.display import Audio
import io

LNG2 = 'ru'

def loraSpeak(text):
    print('LORA:' + text)
    global LNG2
    with io.BytesIO() as f:
        gTTS(text=text, lang=LNG2).write_to_fp(f)
        f.seek(0)
        return Audio(f.read(), autoplay=True)

loraSpeak('привет, я - Лора')
```

Если по какой-то причине вы захотите оставить вариант с файлом, то лучшее, что вы можете сделать - это предварительно создать RAM-диск (tmpfs в linux) и сохранять файл туда. Таким образом получится, что не произойдёт взаимодействия с медленным диском - файл мгновенно разместится в ОЗУ и мгновенно (быстрее, чем с физического диска) прочитается в следующей строчке вашего кода: 
`os.system('start asisResp.wav')`

Answer (score 0):

Гугл отдает голос в mp3 - поэтому его не получается проиграть в pygame напрямую.

```
import pydub
import pygame.mixer

f = io.BytesIO()
obj = gTTS(text="привет", lang='ru', slow=False)
obj.write_to_fp(f)
f.seek(0)
audio = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(f, format='mp3')
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(audio.raw_data)
sound.play()
```

Или если есть место для временных файлов

```
import tempfile
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.mp3')

....
```